# Reason for my app going to suspended state?

Tags: ios, swift, background, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am created a location tracking ios app(using CocoaLumberjack library to write log file).So background location update is enabled and working for my testing(I nearly running of upto 8 hours in background). When app goes to live store. There is lot of issue occurred in our app. When app went to background location tracking is not working properly. It's not send user location to server for some period of time. So i get log file from client and reviewed there is a time gap in log file. i frequently getting user location(every one second). So i thought app went to suspended state at the time of gap occurs in log file? Why app goes into suspended state even i am getting frequently location in background? is there a reason for app going to suspended state? searched lot can't find any valid details?

```
 func startTimer()
{
    if bgTimer == nil
    {
        bgTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startLocationChanges), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func stopTimer()
{
    if bgTimer != nil
    {
        bgTimer?.invalidate()
        bgTimer = nil
    }
}

@objc func startLocationChanges() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //let lastLocation = locations.last!

    // Do something with the location.
    /*print(lastLocation)
    let logInfo = "BGLocationManager didUpdateLocations : " + "\(lastLocation)"
    AppDelegate.appDelegate().writeLoggerStatement(strInfo: logInfo)*/

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
        // Location updates are not authorized.
        manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        return
    }

    // Notify the user of any errors.
}



func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationDidEnterBackground: when the user quits.
    self.writeLoggerStatement(strInfo: "applicationDidEnterBackground")
    appstate = "Background"

    if CoreDataUtils.isUserLoggedIn(entityName: "UserInfo") == true {
        let user = CoreDataUtils.fetchCurrentUser(entityName: "UserInfo")
        if user!.isGPSActive == "1"
        {
            if backgroundTaskIdentifier != nil
            {
                application.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
                backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            }

            backgroundTaskIdentifier = application.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
                //UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
            })

            BGLocationManager.shared.startTimer()

            let logInfo = String(format:"applicationDidEnterBackground backgroundTimeRemaining : %f",(Double)(application.backgroundTimeRemaining / 60))
            self.writeLoggerStatement(strInfo: logInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can’t help you unless you share code. E.g., show us how you requested background location updates.

Comment: @vinoth87 Check if app get crashed. This should not happen if your app register for background location updates. And also I personally feel app should not be fetching location update on every 1 second. try to optimised it.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre app is not getting crashed. I added crashlytics. There is no crashes in there.

Comment: @Rob edited questions and added code. When app goes to background started timer to fetch location information at regular interval.. Can you please review it?

Comment: 1. If you want to keep getting updates why do you say `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`? You cannot run in the background unless you are actively updating locations.  2. You cannot start a timer after you’ve gone into the background. And you don’t need one. Just turn on updates and when you go into the background they continue. Using a timer for location is totally wrong.

Comment: @matt when i am testing in local it works fine for 8 hours. If timer is  a main problem how is it working for me? But i will change it as you recommended. Already started timer will run in background?

Comment: An already started timer will run in the background if you run in the background. But if you stop updating locations you will not run in the background.

Comment: What does testing in local mean?

Comment: @vinoth87 timer alone can't run your application in background. One you stop your location update app no longer receives location updates and system suspend your app. If your app don't need best level of accuracy then better use significant location updates service.

Comment: @matt so what you guys suggested is i want to startup location manager when application launch and don't want to stop user location update. When app goes background it will work automatically because of background mode enabled right. Reason i used timer is i detect user moving state and if user didn't move then i changed location update interval to 3 seconds otherwise it fetching location every 1 sec. This may saves some battery percentage. Also i want all locations to be accurate so i used bestfornavigation accuracy level.

Comment: @matt Also significant location change is also initiated to startup app when its been terminated or into suspended state.

Comment: If you are going to use significant location change, you do not need to run in the background and you should not attempt to. That is what we are trying to get you to understand. Either you continue using foreground location by continuing to run when you go into the background, or you ask for a background location mode which is performed for you by the system without your running in the background at all.

Comment: @matt how long will it run in background? i don't bother about battery drain now. will it move to suspend state by any chance?

Comment: It will be suspended immediately if you do not run in the background in the way I described. It may even be terminated. That doesn't matter because the "background modes" are run by the system, not by your app; they will continue to work just fine. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few observations:

1. The `beginBackgroundTask` only buys you 30 seconds, not 8 hours. (In iOS versions prior to 13, this was 3 minutes, not 30 seconds, but the point still stands.) Bottom line, this is designed to allow you to finish some short, finite length task, not keeping the app running indefinitely. Worse, if you don’t call `endBackgroundTask` in its completion handler, the app will be unceremoniously terminated when the allotted time has expired.
2. There are two basic patterns to background location updates.

   - If the app is a navigation app, then you can keep the app running in the background. But keeping standard location services running in the background will kill the user’s battery in a matter of a few hours. So Apple will only authorize this if your app absolutely requires it (e.g. your app is an actual navigation app, not just an app that happens to want to keep track of locations for some other reason).
   - The other pattern is [significant change service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service). With this service, your app will be suspended, but the OS will wake it to deliver location updates, and then let it be suspended again. See [Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background). This isn’t as precise as the standard location services, but because the app isn’t constantly running and because it doesn’t have to spin up GPS hardware, it consumes far less power.
3. When testing these sorts of background interactions, you do not want to be attached to the Xcode debugger. Running it via the debugger actually changes the app lifecycle, preventing it from ever suspending.
4. As one doesn’t generally keep the app running in the background indefinitely, that means that you will want to remove that `Timer` related code.

Comment: isn't this 3 minute time reduced to 30 seconds in iOS 13?

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks.